# Template parent class method call

Tags: c++, templates

My situation looks something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class BaseClass1
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class ChildClass1 : public BaseClass1<int>
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        // do stuff
    };
};

template<typename T>
class BaseClass2 : public BaseClass1<T>
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class ChildClass2 : BaseClass2<int>
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        // call ChildClass1::foo()
        BaseClass1::foo();
    };
};
```

My ultimate aim is to be able to call ChildClass1::foo() inside ChildClass2::foo(), but I'm clearly doing something wrong. All of these classes are defined in their own header files, along with all their method definitions.

Then I have a file where I'm trying to instantiate ChildClass2. It looks something like this:

```
#include "ChildClass1.hpp"
#include "ChildClass2.hpp"

ChildClass2 obj;
obj.foo();
```

When I attempt to compile, I get a link error:

> [...] unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall BaseClass1::foo(void)" [...] referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall ChildClass2::foo(void)"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, and/or a better way to achieve my aim if I'm going about it in the wrong way? Also, a more descriptive title would probably be good if anyone can think of one! Thanks.

Comment: ChildClass1 and ChildClass2 are unrelated classes. Without an *instance* of the former, there nothing for the latter to invoke.

Comment: @WhozCraig, But is ChildClass2 not an instance of ChildClass1? The error I'm getting seems to suggest that this is correct, but I'm messing up my #includes somewhere...

Comment: First, ChildClass2 isn't an "instance" of *anything*. its a *type*. Secondly, the ChildClass2 type is neither synonymous with, nor a derivation of, ChildClass1. They're different types. The only thing they share is a common base class, and that only if they both provide the same `T` in their lineage. Honestly I think you're *trying* to develop a multi-inheritance schema, but its hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code can do what you wanted. 
First you can't call BaseClass1::foo() in ChildClass2::foo(), because BaseClass1::foo() is a pure virtual function.

Second, your ChildClass2 is a child of BaseClass1, the same as ChildClass1, so the two classes have no parent-child relationship, you can't call one's function without a *object* of that class.

Comment: I'm not trying to call BaseClass1:foo() - I'm trying to call ChildClass1::foo(). Is this possible? I could access methods of ChildClass1 from inside BaseClass2 couldn't I? So why can't I access those same methods from a subclass of BaseClass2?

Comment: no, it's not possible. your code is calling BaseClass1::foo, which makes no sense. and ChildClass1 has no relation with ChildClass2 apart from the both inherit from BaseClass1, so you can not call ChildClass1::foo() in ChildClass2, you need to pass in a ChildClass1 object.

Comment: But BaseClass2<int> is surely a sub-class of BaseClass1<int> - that is ChildClass1, right?

Comment: no, ChildClass1 is a child class of BaseClass1<int>, you inherited from it!

Answer (score -1):

Your `ChildClass2::foo` method calls `BaseClass1::foo` which isn't defined. Either provide a definition for `BaseClass1::foo` or don't reference it in `ChildClass2::foo` and you shouldn't run into this issue.